# ETL triple reference timeKey, subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, etl, star-schema

I am writing an ETL and I am trying to make my dimension reference the time dimension three times. But I can't even get the first one right.

The error says:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

My code:

```
SELECT e.eventName, 
       e.eventType, 
       e.numberOfPersons,
      (SELECT  timeKey 
       FROM    starSchema.dbo.timeDim 
       JOIN    reservation r 
              ON r.reservationDate = timeDim.DATE) AS resDate, 
       e.eventStartDate, 
       e.eventEndDate, 
       contact.name, 
       customer.company
FROM   events e 
JOIN   reservation r 
       ON e.reservationId = r.reservationId
JOIN   customer 
       ON e.customerId = customer.customerId
JOIN   contact 
       ON customer.contactId = contact.contactId
```

I am trying to join the source datetime with my time dimension and return timeKey.

My goal is to have a timeKey(int) to reference the time dimension.

I want to do this with r.reservationdate, e.eventStartDate and e.eventEndDate.

Picture of my time Dimension:

[image: Picture of my time Dimension]

Picture of Source:

[image: Picture of Source]

Comment: @StelioK: thanks for wanting to improve posts here. However, if you can make your edit messages a little more diplomatic, it may be appreciated `:-)` - not everyone is a native English speaker here. For me, the question is whether they have made an effort prior to asking a question, and whether they have made an effort in assembling the question.

Comment: Understood and I apologize for being ignorant in my justifications. I didn't realize they were public ;)

Comment: No worries @StelioK. Yep, they can be seen by the person you're editing (they get a notification) and your [history is visible too](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5750208/steliok?tab=activity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want a correlated subquery:

```
(SELECT timeKey FROM starSchema.dbo.timeDim WHERE r.reservationDate = timeDim.DATE) AS resDate,
```

You don't want a `JOIN` in the subquery.  You want the connection to be to the reservation table in the outer query.

Comment: Or just use a normal `JOIN` in the outer query?

Comment: @MatBailie what do you mean with a normal JOIN ? a full join? Left/right join?

Comment: @J.Meijerink - Whatever is appropriate in your situation....  if you know there is always a row, then it's an `INNER JOIN`...  I just mean that there is no apparent need for a correlated sub-query at all.